# Can elements be grouped in a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML and CSS

http://jsbin.com/uciya5/3/edit

where the problem is that the radio buttons are treated as individual elements and therefore inherent the properties of `class="cellData"`. Notice how wide the radio buttons are spaced vertically.

```
<div class="cellData">
  <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" checked/> Individuel <br>
  <input name="ctype" value="course" type="radio" /> Course </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to control this vertical spacing of the radio buttons, or perhaps wrap a DIV around them to protect them?

**Update**
Removed template tags.

Comment: Just a side note: using `<` and `>` as part of your template variables is a Bad Idea (if only because it's confusing) when you're using HTML. You should switch to `{TMPL_VAR CO}` or `#TMPL_VAR CO#`, etc.

Comment: You already have controlled the vertical spacing by specifying the line height of the `.cellData` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another `class` to the `div` containing radio buttons:

```
<div class="cellData cellRadios">
```

with CSS (similar to this):

```
.cellRadios { line-height: 1 }
```

**See:** http://jsbin.com/uciya5/2

Provided that in your CSS you define `.cellRadios` *after* `.cellData`, the `line-height` from `.cellRadios` will be the one that's applied.

I'd probably also change `.cellRadios` to a better name.

---

If you prefer it, you could instead wrap the radio buttons in an extra `div`, as you suggested in your question.

```
<div class="cellData">
    <div class="cellRadios">
        <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" <TMPL_VAR IN>/> Individuel
        <br>
        <input name="ctype" value="course" type="radio" <TMPL_VAR CO>/> Course
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete this from the CellData stye:  line-height:4em

You could also try using a table, it would be a lot simpler.